# Windows Server 2008 Terminal Server: Reconnect by Client Name

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, session

I'm in a bind right now: we're setting up a few Windows 7 Embedded client machines that are supposed to connect to a Windows Server 2008 R2 terminal server, which in turn is running the programme that the clients are to use. We've got everything set up so that the clients will log into a domain user and then automatically start their RDP client and connect to the server, and the server will happily and automatically run the programme the clients need.

Our problem, now, is this: all of the clients share a single user account, but they have distinct host/client names. When two or more clients disconnect at the same time, the TS will offer any new clients that connect a choice of sessions to resume, which is extremely confusing to the users. Is it possible to configure the server so that it will instead resume the last session that client used, based on the client name, or would we need to define distinct user names?

Comment: You need to use unique user names for each user.

Comment: That's what we're doing right now, but it'd be cleaner to have a single user. Can't seem to find a way to do it like that though.